# How can I add a character to each string in an array, in a performant way?

Tags: c#, string

I need a good **performance** option for adding a character into a `string[]` like

```
string[] mystring;
mystring[0] = "I1.0"
mystring[1] = "I1.1"
```

into

```
string[] mystring;
mystring[0] = "%I1.0"
mystring[1] = "%I1.1"
```

I need to add `"%"` at the beginning of each new string

I have to edit a large Excel file and need a good performance. Do i have to use `StringBuilder` or `ToCharArray`?

Comment: Are you really sure you need to do this? If all strings need that same prefix, why not change the method that consumes it instead?

Comment: I would suggest trying to just get something working, then see how performance pans out. You may find that that the naive `foreach (var s in mystring) { s = "%" + s; }` might be "fast enough".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is only good for 5+ string operations, otherwise it's just an unnecessary overhead. Just use `+` in your case you can't optimize it very much.

See StringBuilder performance benchmark and comparison [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance).

---

If the performance that you'd see isn't acceptable, I'd recommend to search for a different solution. Re-think if what you're trying to achieve is really needed and maybe come up with some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Way back in the day I saw lots of questions asked about performance of a certain code piece.  The answer we would get is "That's the wrong question.  The question should be 'is it performant enough for my customer, and if not, then the next question should be is this the bottle neck.'"

If I was doing this, I probably would output things as

```
string.format("%{0}", nputString)
```

to get it to work, then see if it was fast enough for my uses.

This is a prime case where I would favor readability and maintainability over performance considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, at the end, "+" works fast enough!

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < count; i1++)
                    {
                        if (adress[i1].Substring(0, 1) != "%") // TIA Portal: Operand hat "%" vorstehen, falls nicht wird hinzugefügt
                        {
                            adress[i1] = "%" + adress[i1];
                        }
                    }
```